# Is there a way to create an attributed string without using NSAttributedString class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on objective-C to swift conversion. For conversion, I am using String for NSString and Array for NSArray. Similarly, when I try to convert NSAttributedString , I could not find a structure type. Is there any structure type that can be used instead of NSAttributedString class or I must and should use NSAttributedString class itself for the conversion

Comment: we can use `NSAttributedString` in swift

Comment: Swift `String` is just for plain text but for color, images, urls etc. you will use `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: NSAttributedString is part of Cocoa, it's in the framework, it's not related to the language.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, you can and should use `NSAttributedString` even if you're writing Swift code.

E.g. As you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620542-attributedtext) the property `attributedText` of `UILabel`
 is of type `NSAttributedString`.